# Building a dynamic select using linq expressions

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am trying to build a dynamic linq select using expressions.

In other words, I would like to build a lambda query like:

```
class User {
 public string UserName {get; set;}
 public List<Group> Groups {get; set;}
}

class Group {
 public string GroupName {get; set;}
 .....
 ..... lots of other members
}

var = context.Set<User>().Select(u=>new {UN = u.UserName, Groups = u.Groups.Select(g => g.GroupName)});
```

I tried using linq.expressions and was able to build a lambda like:

u => new TypeName { UN = u.UserName }

But could not find a way to create the same query using an anonymous type not handling a subquery for the Groups List property.

Comment: It is complicated to create anonymous types at runtime and rarely useful. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to be able to send a list of fields to a lambda query "builder" that would allow me to select data  fields from the User table as well as from the Group table. The complexity is not in creating the query Expression for the Users table but for the Group collection.

Comment: But why do you want to send fields to a query builder? Have you considered Dynamic LINQ? Perhaps show your code for building the top level and explain where your issue is more concretely?

Comment: Dynamic linq allows to retrieve first level members like select("FirstName, LastName"). What I can't do is select("FirstName, Groups.GroupName") i.e. select a member in an ICollection.

Comment: I have no trouble with this working with DynamicLINQ: `Select("new(UserName as Username,Groups.Select(GroupName).ToList() as Groups)")` ?